# Wordpress: Local database to live server

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I have setup a wordpress website at my local machine, intalled wocommerce and did the theme configuration and updates. Its working fine. Then I exported the mysqldump and changed the all local url reference to live url. Then I imported that updated mysqldump in my server phpmyadmin. When I checked the new tables all values are there. Rsynced all local files to server. Then updated the wp-config.php to server database credentials.

The issue is, If I take the live website url in browser, the database automatically updates with basic wordpress table datas. And woocommerce data is not visible through wordpress admin. Do I need to do anything extra changes in the code other than wp-config.php?

While importing mysql database, I got a collation error,

```
#1273 – Unknown collation: ‘utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci’
```

I solved the collation isssue by renaming "utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci"  to "utf8mb4_unicode_ci".

Comment: do you setup new WordPress on live or using WordPress which one on your local machine?

Comment: I setup wordpress in my local machine. Then uploaded the files to live server and updated the url links in the sql files and imported in the server phpmyadmin.

Comment: The best way to migrate website from local server to live through Duplicator plugin. Its easy to implement and update all urls in database automatically

Comment: did you reset your  permalinks ?

Comment: No. But I changed all the local reference of domain name in the sql dump

Comment: then reset it first plain and save it then again reset it postname